# Peugeot 206 2002 16valve twin Cam will not idle. What controls the idle. It doesn't appear to have a stepper motor Help

Tags: idle, peugeot, peugeot-206

It is  a two door coupe and it will not idle i don't understand why. It doesn't appear to have a stepper motor that i can see

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I’d sure like to see a photo of the top of the engine. 2002 model year, I’d suspect has a real throttle cable from the accelerator pedal plus an electronic idle bypass controller.  Send me a photo and I’ll edit your question to add it.